# List of SQL Server features only available for Enterprise

Tags: sql-server

Hello fellow Developers,

I am setting up a copy of the SQL Server Developer edition which is basically Enterprise edition for mock-ups.

Soon I will begin to deploy a few demo apps and would like to know which features are only available through the enterprise license.

Is there a way to have a T-SQL script that looks out for Enterprise only objects and alerts me when I have made an object that would require a Enterprise license in the implementation phase?  That way I could at least make a note of it to clients during demos that an Enterprise License would be required.

Any pointers on how to setup some type of watch for Enterprise Features?

My outline is to have blacklist of entreprise features and the objects associated with them.  Then list them in a table and have the db check each object to see if it falls in that category.  Then hold those violating objects in a table where I can look periodically, or configure a notification through a stored proc.

I am a noob so please feel free to provide constructive feedback.

Comment: There's nothing in TSQL that will do it, you just need to keep an eye on the edition comparison chart https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/cloud-platform/sql-server-editions

Comment: Since of course you're keeping your database schema in SSDT projects in source control you could possibly create [custom analysis rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172133.aspx) to do it, but I'd say it would be a fair amount of work.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the DMV sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features. It should tell you if there are features of Enterprise in use for the current DB. However, it will not tell you which objects make use of the feature. 
Good luck.